# How to include Composer dependencies in a Git repo

Tags: php, git, jenkins, composer-php, silverstripe

When creating sites using a framework like [Silverstripe](https://www.silverstripe.org/) I often want to use helper modules like **gridfieldextensions** and **lumberjack**.

I therefore use `composer require` to add the dependencies.

However when I follow my regular development work flow and use `git add -A` to add the module to the repo rather than the code being added to the repo I get a reference to it.

[image: git reference rather than code]

This causes problems when I then try to clone the site elsewhere (using **Jenkins** or another developer). The `git clone` or `git pull` leaves an empty directory.

I solve this by deleting the `.git` dir of the module and adding all the files.

Is there a better way to do this? Is using `git submodule` an option?

Comment: There is a file called .gitignore .  Otherwise it is horrible do what you want to do.

Comment: @Mattia how do you mean? Use git ignore to ignore the dependancy's `.git` dir?

Comment: I ignore my vendor directory.  Add the composer.json, and after cloning/pulling follow with a composer call.   I stay away from submodules.

Comment: @Progrock thanks the only issue is that these Silverstripe Modules are placed at the project root out side of the vendor dir as they are used in production. I'm trying what I think is @Mattia suggestion and ignoring the `.git` dirs and adding them that way.

Comment: You can use **composer update**. Your workflow would be to clone your project repo, then **composer update** to pull down all the required repos such as gridfieldextensions.

Comment: @GavinBruce thanks. I will have to give that a go and adapt my Jenkins Job

Comment: It should be composer install over composer update, unless you are absolutely sure you want the remote server to run on different versions on what you were running your self during that exact time of testing. 

The idea is that when you deploy a project, it contains the composer.lock and when you run composer install it will read the lock file of the versions that were released when you were working on it. 

Eg. ignore the composer installed module directories and vendor from the repo and add the non composer ones that you did for the project.

Comment: @FinBoWa thanks I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: I tweaked my comment to contain the "vendor" directory to be also ignored in the repo. Just to clarify that there isn't anything wrong running composer update on the remote, but one should note what the comoser update causes over composer install :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere i found a good *.gitignor*e file that ignores everything and i have to tell it to include the custom modules for my project. It's like:

```
# ignore everything...
/*

# ...but
!/.htaccess
!/.gitignore
!/composer.json
!/composer.lock

!/Capfile
!/Gemfile
!/favicon.ico
!/touch-icon-*


!/mysite
!/some-module
#...other modules

# theme stuff
!/themes/
**/.sass-cache
**/node_modules

!**/node_modules/_manifest_exclude

#no assets in general, but /assets/.htaccess
!/assets
/assets/*
!assets/.htaccess
```

As FinBoWa already said you need the *composer.json* and *composer.lock* file in your project and running

> composer install

on another machine it'll install the packages in the versions saved in the composer.lock file on that machine

> composer install --no-dev

will only install the "normal" requirements, no dev-requirements like phpunit or other stuff you only need for developing or testing but not live

> composer install --no-dev -o

will also optimize (-o) the auto loader, so it'll be a bit faster.

> composer update

will update your packages, which might have funny side effects and break your site. So use it carefully and test afterwards.

> composer update silverstripe/framework

will just update that package and finally

> composer update silverstripe/*

will update all packages by the vendor silverstripe (e.g. framework and cms package)

See also:

- [gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)
- [composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install)

Comment: Thanks. I had not been using composer on production servers preferring to rely on Git alone I will update my deployment process.

Comment: I once found a git post-merge hook that installs composer stuff for you (and runs dev/build)  when you run "git pull". You might adjust it for your needs: see https://gist.github.com/wernerkrauss/33dcb098c05ed063be22